# MySQL query to search for people with specific skills

Tags: mysql, join

I'm inexperienced with SQL... i'm trying to figure out how to search my database for personnel with specific skills.

I want to generate a table which contains two columns, Name and Skill(s)

The initial search is currently performing this query:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    User_Skills LEFT JOIN 
        skills ON User_Skills.Skill_id = Skills.id 
WHERE   Skill_id = 5 OR Skill_id = 7 // 5 & 7 are variables.
```

This generates results like this:

```
User_id     Skill_id    id   name
1000           5       5    Designer
1000           7       7    Data Analysis
1001           7       7    Data Analysis
1001           5       5    Designer
```

The question is... am I doing this right? I'm searching for specific skills.. once I find the skills, should I then use the User_id's to perform a second query? I dont know if I need the name returned twice, as it would if I joined the Users table to the above query. Or should I JOIN the User table, then cull data I don't need programatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recomend that you have a look at Group_Concat

[GROUP_CONCAT useful GROUP BY extension](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/04/group_concat-useful-group-by-extension/).

Comment: That's really cool! I've never used the GROUP functions in SQL!

Being very new with databases, I'm wondering if you could point me in the right direction.

I don't know how to THINK about how to get there results I want.

Say if I want to return all users who have skill id 10 and skill id 12, When I query using WHERE SKill_id = 10 AND Skill_id = 12, it shows no results. If I do Skill_id = 10 OR Skill_id = 12, it won't give me the results I want because I need users who have BOTH skills, not one or the other.
These are the results I'd like:
    User    Skill_id
    Fred    10,11